# How to avoid the (potential) error by conversion when assigning a char to a char with ternary operator

Tags: c, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have the following Code:

```
void foo(char* char_ptr, unsigned short len) {
    char c = len != 0 ? char_ptr[0] : '\0';
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

I get the following warning:

> Clang-Tidy: Narrowing conversion from 'int' to signed type 'char' is implementation-defined

What conversion is this thing talking about? I have only `char`s everywhere. How can I avoid this (potential) error?
This looks like another case of "There's some implicit magic going on that you just have to know about". Is there a place where I can lookup all the magic that the c-compiler is implicitly doing?

Comment: Re “Is there a place where I can lookup all the magic that the c-compiler is implicitly doing?”: Start with [the C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).

Comment: @EricPostpischil casting just the '\0' doesnt shut the warning down. How weird that a literal with single quotes is an int and not a char!

Comment: @AdrianMole casting the whole statement shuts down the warning, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpreting the information from [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other), specifically in the "Conditional Operator" section, subsections (3) and (1), we see:

> (3) Performs a conversion from the result of the evaluation to the
> common type, defined as follows:
>
> > (1) if the expressions have arithmetic
> > type, the common type is the type after [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions)

Then, looking at the linked "usual arithmetic conversions", we see:

> (4) Otherwise, both operands are integers. Both operands undergo
> integer promotions (see below); then, ...

Those *integer promotions* will cause **both** expressions to be promoted to `int` types - even if you explicitly cast the second, as in `char c = len != 0 ? char_ptr[0] : (char)'\0';`.

So, in order to silence the warning, the *result* of the conditional expression (which will be of `int` type) needs to be cast to a `char`, as in:

```c
    char c = (char)(len != 0 ? char_ptr[0] : '\0');
```

---

From [this Draft C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.5.15 Conditional Operator**
> ...
> 5 If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result type that would be determined by the
> usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands,
> is the type of the result.

Which appears to confirm the information presented by cppreference.com.